# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Учетная запись уже существует. '

Tags: c#, .net

есть проблема.
нужно реализовать создание пользователя под Windows
мой код срабатывает, но хотелось бы добавить условие, если User_Name n1 уже существует, то пусть создаст n2
сейчас если два раза запустить код, то вылетает на ошибку:
"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Учетная запись уже существует. , что вполне логично...
есть идеи?)

```
private void CreateUser1()
    {
        //Имя пользователя
        string USER_NAME = n1 ;
        //Пароль 
        char[] aPWchars = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };
        System.Security.SecureString oPW = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char cChr in aPWchars)
        {
            oPW.AppendChar(cChr);
        }
        DirectoryEntry oComputer = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
        DirectoryEntry oNewUser = oComputer.Children.Add(USER_NAME, "user");
        IntPtr pString = IntPtr.Zero;
        pString = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(oPW);
        oNewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pString) });
        oNewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "Description", n1 });
        oNewUser.CommitChanges();
        Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(pString);
        DirectoryEntry oGroup = oComputer.Children.Find("Пользователи", "group");
        oGroup.Invoke("Add", new object[] { oNewUser.Path.ToString() });
    }
```

Comment: Оберните внутри функции в блок try ... catch и если приходит ошибка, то верните false. В основной программе сформируйте новое имя и снова вызовите функцию. Лучше так объявить private bool CreateUser1( string USER_NAME ) и имя передавать параметром

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/exceptions/exception-handling